# Adding ComboBox within ToolBar in wxWidgets (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I am a beginner in wxWigets library. I couldn't add a comboBox inside the wxToolbar. Can anyone help me? The code compiles fine, but the container window deosn't show up correctly when I add the wxComboBox into it.

```
CFrame* itemCMultiFrame1 = this;
wxBitmap* toolsBitmaps[1];
toolsBitmaps[0] = new wxBitmap(open_xpm);

wxToolBar* toolBar = new wxToolBar(this, 12423, wxDefaultPosition,
    wxDefaultSize, wxTB_NODIVIDER | wxTB_FLAT | wxTB_HORIZONTAL);

wxArrayString strings;
strings.Add(wxT("1"));
strings.Add(wxT("2"));
strings.Add(wxT("3"));
strings.Add(wxT("4"));
wxComboBox* combo = new wxComboBox(this, 12322,wxT("1"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize,strings, wxCB_DROPDOWN);
toolBar->AddTool(wxID_SAVE, wxT("open.xpm"), *toolsBitmaps[0], wxT("Select file"), wxITEM_CHECK);
toolBar->AddControl(combo);
toolBar->EnableTool(wxID_SAVE,true);
toolBar->EnableTool(12322, true);
toolBar->SetMargins(0, 0);

wxBoxSizer* itemBoxSizer10 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
itemBoxSizer10->Add(toolBar, 0, wxEXPAND, 0);

toolBar->Realize();
itemCMultiFrame1->SetToolBar(toolBar);
```

Comment: Since you are trying to add the combo box to the Toolbar, wouldn't it be nice to replace `this` (which is the `CFrame` pointer) in the `wxComboBox` constructor with the pointer to the `wxToolBar` which is `toolBar` in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [toolbar sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/WX_3_0_2/samples/toolbar/toolbar.cpp#L444) shows how to do it.

When you're trying to find out how to do something with wxWidgets, *always* try looking in the samples, they're very helpful when learning.